# Where are my rhythmbox library folders stored?

Tags: rhythmbox

I tried

`rm ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/ ~/.cache/rhythmbox/ ~/.gconf/apps/rhythmbox/ -r`

but that only ended up removing the database. I want to remove some folders in particular. How do I do that? Are there symlinks involved?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean 'where does Rhythmbox import the physical music files to?'

Comment: When I goto Edit > Preferences > Music > Library, it tells me `Multiple locations are set` and I only want to be set one location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you select your directory in the preferences, it automatically reverts to "multiple locations". This is because there is at lease one other location set automatically by the Ubuntu One Music Store:

```
~/.local/share/ubuntuone/Purchased from Ubuntu One/
```

Now, don't delete this directory :-)

You can check what directories are set as library locations by opening the gconf-editor (hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gconf-editor`), then navigate to `apps` → `rhythmbox` and check the "library locations" key.

This is what it should look like after you've set your library location to ~/Music:

[image]

I recommend you just leave it there, and just use the gconf-editor to make sure there aren't any other locations set. But you can also delete the u1 music store entry (though I wouldn't be surprised if the ubuntu one plugin just added it again).

In case you do decide to delete either the directory, the gconf entry for it, or both, be safe in the knowledge that you can't break anything by doing that, none the less, you may as well just leave them be; in case you decide to use the Ubuntu One Music Store one day. They don't slow down Rhythmbox at all; you won't even know they're there.

Comment: I searched all the folders, and it didnt occur to me to check with gconf :/ Just need to remove a few folders withing the Music folder, thats all!

Comment: RhythmBox is not appearing under the apps section. On Ubuntu 12.04. Installed gconf-editor. I see other apps like Banshee, but not RhythmBox. Either, die to the tight integration, it's been moved to system or something, or I'm not doing something right. Help :(

Comment: @YatharthROCK: You'll need to install dconf-tools, then browse to /org/gnome/rhythmbox/rhythmdb in dconf-editor.