which folders should i include with deja-dup to keep rhythmbox data i.e. ratings cover art genre
Can anyone tell me which folders I should include with deja-dup backup so I can restore the data in rhythmbox music player. If I don't add something to deja-dup all I get from a restore are the music files themselves, the titles, and the author info. Missing are the song ratings, the genre, and the cover art links. If I have to do a restore this takes weeks to manually recreate this data.

Stephano wrote an answer that might help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/21329/where-are-my-rhythmbox-library-folders-stored

Cover-art is stored @ {HOME}/.cache/rythmbox/abum-art . Take a look at the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/454418/how-can-i-get-rhythmbox-to-display-the-correct-album-cover-art
